# refreshing AWS token and secret in ECS with Java

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I can get a token and secret in an ECS container from 169.254.170.2$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI (see https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-fargate-access-aws-services/).

The AWS Java SDK v1 appears to wrap this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/amazonaws/auth/ContainerCredentialsProvider.html

It also seems to provide methods to check the expiration date and refresh the retrieved data.

The AWS Java SDK v2 also appears to wrap this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper.html

It doesn't give an expiry date though, so how is this meant to be used? The impression I get is that the token lasts for less than a day.

The AWS Java SDK v2 also appears to wrap another way: https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/auth/credentials/ContainerCredentialsProvider.Builder.html

It doesn't give a refresh method or the expiry date but the parent class (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/auth/credentials/HttpCredentialsProvider.Builder.html) allows you to set whether it gets asynchronously refreshed, and to set a thread name (presumably to handle the async refresh) but there is no documentation around how to use asyncThreadName.

So how can I get the token and secret and know how/when to refresh them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to AWS Support, adding a call to asyncCredentialUpdateEnabled(true) does the refreshing in the background without any further effort.