# Replacement of AWSCredentialsProvider#refresh() in AWS SDK Java v2

Tags: aws-sdk-java-2.0, aws-sdk-java

I used to have a custom implementation of the `AWSCredentialsProvider`'s `refresh()` method then when I migrated to the AWS SDK v2, the `AwsCredentialsProvider` does not provide such a method anymore. How should I implement the refresh credentials mechanism in the new v2 SDK?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67800581/refreshing-aws-token-and-secret-in-ecs-with-java) and the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/migration-client-credentials.html), it appears that refresh now happens automatically in the background. This likely means you won't be able to hook into that action with custom logic if you are upgrading to v2.